# Umbraco.library:DateDiff() Throws an error when used with umbraco Datepicker document type field value

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I am trying to compare a **date value set in Datepicker** (an umbraco document type field) with **current date** (umbraco.library:FormatDateTime(umbraco.library:CurrentDate()) in an **XSLT** provided by **umbraco cms(version 4.7)**.

The function i used for this was,

```
  Umbraco.library:DateDiff($expiryDate, $currentDate, 's')
```

The XSLT throws the following error,

```
 Error occured

 System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. 
 at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles     styles) 
 at umbraco.library.DateDiff(String firstDate, String secondDate, String diffType)
```

I am sure this is related to some issue with datepicker value. Plain date string instead of datepicker value is working well.

Please help me out if any one went through such a situation.

**Edit :**
Please see my date diff code used in XSLT below,

```
  <xsl:variable name="currentDate" select="umbraco.library:FormatDateTime(umbraco.library:CurrentDate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')"/>  
  Now:<xsl:value-of select="$currentDate"/><br/> 

  <xsl:variable name="expiryDate" select="umbraco.library:FormatDateTime($node/expiryDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')"/>
  Exp:<xsl:value-of select="$expiryDate"/><br/> // Where **$node/expiryDate** is my datepicker value

   <xsl:variable name="diffInSecs" select="umbraco.library:DateDiff($expiryDate, $currentDate, 's')"/> 
  Diff :<xsl:value-of select="$diffInSecs"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must first make sure that both dates are in the same known format, so you should use this:

```
<xsl:variable name="currentDate"
   select="umbraco.library:FormatDateTime(umbraco.library:CurrentDate(),
      'dd/MM/yyyy')" />
```

and:

```
<xsl:variable name="formattedExpiryDate"
   select="umbraco.library:FormatDateTime($expiryDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')" />
```

Comment: I've tried that too.. But still resulted in the same error. But by providing the first argument of dateDiff() as $formattedExpiryDate the error happens. I've tried giving hard coded date string instead of $formattedExpiryDate and that worked.

Comment: No problem with the second argument $currentDate. But the issue is with the first argument of dateDiff(),ie, $formattedExpiryDate which is set from a datepicker field value.

Comment: @Harun - Try using the format `yyyy-MM-dd` (or even `dd-MM-yyyy` according to [DateDiff()](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/datediff)). It's possible localisation could be the issue. Test with a *safe* date such 01/01/2012 in your DatePicker to confirm this. To see if this is actually the case, you might need to check the `Skip Errors` box to get past the parsing error and test it on the front end with actual data.

Comment: @ Goran Mottram, Sorry for the delayed reply....The dateDiff() does not have any problem with the format of the parameters. For example, i have checked with hard coded date string values (1st parameter in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format and the 2nd parameter in 'dd-MM-yyyy' format and vice versa). The error occurs only when i use the variable set from datepicker doc field as first parameter (current date set to another variable as 2nd parameter does not creates any problem.I checked this by using the mentioned variable as 2nd parameter and 1st parameter as hard coded string). See EDIT section in Question.